# No suitable method found for addListener(<anonymous ChangeListener<java.time.Duration>>)

Tags: java, javafx

I've trouble with the following code. It's showing error while implementing the following code section. It's a code on JavaFX MediaPlayer project.

```
mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Duration> observable, Duration oldValue, Duration newValue) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });
```

It shows the following error.

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Rmedia\src\rmedia\FXMLDocumentController.java:75: error: no suitable method found for addListener(<anonymous ChangeListener<java.time.Duration>>)
        mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Duration>() {
method Observable.addListener(InvalidationListener) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; <anonymous ChangeListener<java.time.Duration>> cannot be converted to InvalidationListener)
method ObservableValue.addListener(ChangeListener<? super javafx.util.Duration>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; <anonymous ChangeListener<java.time.Duration>> cannot be converted to ChangeListener<? super javafx.util.Duration>)
```

1 error

What should I do to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `javafx.util.Duration` in your controller class instead of `java.time.Duration`, similar to what Dawood has mentioned. However, note that there is no "choice" here - JavaFX API uses `javafx.util.Duration`, and you must follow that.

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix this bug, you need to sort out your imports.  You've imported `javafx.util.Duration` in some classes, and `java.time.Duration` in other classes.

You need to decide which of these two classes you want to use, and make sure your `import` statements across all your classes are referring to the same one.